# Compile error calling .mm class method from ObjC code

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xmp

I'm trying to use the Adobe XMP Toolkit SDK to attach an XMP to some PNG files. The SDK provides some examples and I've modified one of them to fit my needs. The SDK is written in C++ so the example class I've modified is a .mm class.

This is the class:

```
void attachXMPToImage ( string * rdf, string imageName, string software, string softVersion, string referencia, string fecha )
{
//    if ( argc != 2 ) // 2 := command and 1 parameter
//    {
//        cout << "usage: ModifyingXMP (filename)" << endl;
//        return 0;
//    }

    string filename = imageName;
    string rdfFile = *rdf;

    if(!SXMPMeta::Initialize())
    {
         cout << "Could not initialize toolkit!";
      // return -1;
    }

    XMP_OptionBits options = 0;
    #if UNIX_ENV
        options |= kXMPFiles_ServerMode;
    #endif
}
```

I'm not posting the entire class as the problem here is calling this method from my ObjC code.

This class has its own header that looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XmpWriter : NSObject

+ (void)attachXMPToImage:(NSString*)rdf
          imageName:(NSString*)imageName
           software:(NSString*)software
        softVersion:(NSString*)softVersion
         referencia:(NSString*)referencia
              fecha:(NSString*)fecha;

@end
```

Then, from one of my other classes, I try to call that method:

```
 [XmpWriter attachXMPToImage:nil
                      imageName:k_IMAGE_NAME
                   software:@"My iOS App"
                softVersion:@"v. 1.0"
                 referencia:@""
                      fecha:timeString];
```

but when I try to compile, I get an error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XmpWriter",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in Myclass.o

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From:http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html It supports Macintosh, Windows, as well as UNIX. No words about IOS.

Comment: It supports iOS as well, and the static libraries needed are compiled for iOS. [link](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/xmp/pdfs/XMP%20SDK%20Release%20cc-2016-08/XMP-Toolkit-SDK-Overview.pdf)

Comment: If you have sources, then it shouldn't be a problem: add new project as static library in you workspace with them, link that library to your app.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I've been able to find an example and I've fixed the problem.

The problem was in the way I called the method in the .mm class. I had to change it in:

```
+ (void) attachXMPToImage:(NSString*)rdf imageName:(NSString*)imageName software:(NSString*)software softVersion:(NSString*)softVersion referencia:(NSString*)referencia fecha:(NSString*)fecha
```